# smoothly transition from an animation layer to the other in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two layers of animation and I'm trying to SMOOTHLY transition between these two layers when I click a button.

```
public void OnButtonClicked(){
animator.SetLayerWeight(layerIndex, 1f);
}
```

For some reasons I don't know, the animation is not smooth at all. It looks really bad when I click the button and the new animation that I'm setting its layer weight starts

Answer (score 0):

[Animator.SetLayerWeight()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetLayerWeight.html) sets the weight of the layer at the given index.
It doesn't interpolates the weight value. It just immediately set it to a desired value.

So to animate this you can use a tweener library. Or you can animate it yourself with coroutines:

```cs
private IEnumerator AnimateWeightsTo(float goalValue)
{
    float startValue = animator.GetLayerWeight(layerIndex);
    for (float i = 0f; i <= 1f; i += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        animator.SetLayerWeight(layerIndex, Mathf.Lerp(startValue, goalValue, i));
        yield return null;
    }

    animator.SetLayerWeight(layerIndex, goalValue);
}
```

Then start this coroutine. Also if you want another layer to decrease at the same time, you can write this:

```cs
private IEnumerator AnimateWeightsTo(int oldLayerIndex, int newLayerIndex, float goalValue)
{
    float newStartValue = animator.GetLayerWeight(newLayerIndex);
    float oldtartValue = animator.GetLayerWeight(oldLayerIndex);

    for (float i = 0f; i <= 1f; i += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        animator.SetLayerWeight(newLayerIndex, Mathf.Lerp(newStartValue, goalValue, i));
        animator.SetLayerWeight(oldLayerIndex, Mathf.Lerp(oldStartValue, 0f, i));
        yield return null;
    }

    animator.SetLayerWeight(newLayerIndex, goalValue);
    animator.SetLayerWeight(oldLayerIndex, 0f);
}
```

Here `oldLayerIndex` - previous layer that must "fade out", `newLayerIndex` - the layer you're switching to.